# Datatable Hide rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need help to HIDE the rows from the Datatable,

When **User selects "Show All"** from the Dropdown, the complete Datatable should be rendered,

Otherwise **when the User selects "Hide USA"**,
 
I want to **hide the rows whose Country Column's value is "USA"**.
So need some kind of hide/show toggle functionality of Datatable depending on the column's value.

Here's my Sample code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var table = $('#example').DataTable();

            $("#choice").on("change",function(){

                var _val = $(this).val();

                 if(_val == 2){   
                        table
                        .columns(2)
                        .search('USA',true)
                        .draw();
                  }
                  else{
                    table
                    .columns()
                    .search('')
                    .draw(); 
                  }
            });
        } );



    </script>

    <style>
        #choice{
            width: 135px;
            height: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <select name="choice" id="choice">
        <option value="1">Show All</option>
        <option value="2">Hide USA</option>
    </select>

    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <th>USA</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <th>USA</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <th>Mexico</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <th>Brazil</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <th>Japan</th>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**My current code is Hiding "Non USA" rows, 

Whereas I want to hide rows, whose "Country" column has "USA"**

Comment: This reads like  a "Give me code!" question. You haven't really showed what you have tried. And a quick google search brings up a lot of good results.

Comment: sorry, I've updated what I tried and some related logic, apologizes I can't share my actual project code, that's why the initial short question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) of DataTable, and specified the value with regex, for example:

**Hide Non 61 Age**

```
table
    .columns(1)
    .search('^(?:(?!61).)*$\r?\n?', true, false)
    .draw();
```

**Show All**

```
table
    .columns()
    .search('')
    .draw();
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/egsqb68u/1/

**UPDATE:**

Hide USA:

```
table
    .columns(2) //The index of column to search
    .search('^(?:(?!USA).)*$\r?\n?', true, false) //The RegExp search all string that not cointains USA
    .draw();
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/egsqb68u/2/

Comment: Hi, can you please explain me what this search parameter means "^(?:(?!61).)*$\r?\n?" ?

Comment: Also what the true, false parameters mean, which you've passed to search ?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje the first parameter is an RegExp `^(?:(?!61).)*$\r?\n?`, which filter different values to `61`, the next parameter is the indicator for regular expression and last parameter is the smart indicator, plase read the documentacion https://datatables.net/reference/api/search() and for regex see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: I've updated the Question, My current code is Hiding "Non USA" rows, Whereas I want to hide rows, whose "Country" column has "USA", can you please help me out?

Comment: Thanks! Big help :)

Comment: This answer is amazing and does what I was going to do in 30 lines of code in 3. My only add on, for people who already have declarted their dt object and are having trouble getting the table functions to work, use table = $(' selector ').dataTable().api(); to select the table before using these functions